# Bookmarklet JavaScript - add a character X to existing contents of web page element

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, execcommand

The code I have below does the copy and flashes a brief confirmation message.  I need it to instead add a character X in front of existing contents of that web page element:

<< ? - if you don't know just walk on by, if you need clarification - ask

```js
javascript:(function() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("mergeFields-input-text");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");

    tempAlert("COPIED SUBJECT", 500);
    function tempAlert(msg, duration) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:1%;left:35%;background-color:white;");
        el.innerHTML = msg;
        document.body.appendChild(el);

        setTimeout(function(){
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            }, duration
        );
    }
})();
```

**11.1.18 Version**

```js
javascript:(function() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("mergeFields-input-text");
    copyText.innerHTML = "-" + copyText.innerHTML();

    tempAlert("ADDED", 500);
    function tempAlert(msg, duration) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:1%;left:35%;background-color:white;");
        el.innerHTML = msg;
        document.body.appendChild(el);

        setTimeout(function(){
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            }, duration
        );
    }
})();
```

**11.1.18 V2**

```js
javascript:(function() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("mergeFields-input-text");
    copyText.value = "-" + copyText.value();

    tempAlert("ADDED", 500);
    function tempAlert(msg, duration) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:1%;left:35%;background-color:white;");
        el.innerHTML = msg;
        document.body.appendChild(el);

        setTimeout(function(){
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            }, duration
        );
    }
})();
```

Comment: Something like `copyText.innerHTML = "X" + copyText.innerHTML;`?

Comment: @Barmar - where in my code above would that need to go or what to replace?

Comment: Right after the line that starts with `var CopyText`.

Comment: I added a **11.1.18 Version** in my post above with your code.  If that's what you meant - it does not do anything when tested

Comment: `innerHTML` isn't a function, it's a property that contains the contents of a DOM element. This is really basic JavaScript any web developer should recognize.

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` isn't a function, it's a property that contains the current contents of DOM element. So you shouldn't have `()` after it.

```html
<a href='javascript:(function() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("mergeFields-input-text");
    copyText.value = "-" + copyText.value;})()'>Click me</a>
<input id="mergeFields-input-text" value="initial contents">
```

Comment: I took that code and put it through "Bookmarklet Creator", then put resulting code into a bookmarklet, but it does nothing

Comment: It works in my snippet, it's not obvious what you did differently. What kind of element is `mergeFields-input-text`? If it's an input field, you should use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Comment: I don't know what Bookmarklet Creator is. When I google that I find many different sites, I don't know which one you used.

Comment: I updated my post above under **11.1.18 V2** - that's the exact code I am now using when I put it through https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't know what `tempAlert` is, and I left out all the other stuff that seems unrelated.

Comment: `value` isn't a function, either, get rid of the parentheses after it.

Comment: Your code after put through the link above does nothing. However, thanks for no parentheses advice - that does what I needed. However, the webpage where I am using it (DocuSign) treats the same action differently. i.e. if it's done via code vs manually. Via code it adds a character, but fails to recognize it's there. Manually, same character, page recognize it's there and acts the way I need it to.  This is to compensate for DocuSign's changing envelope's name from file's name (desirable result) to template's name, once template is applied. tempAlert is a confirmation flash on the screen.

Comment: Is there any error in the JavaScript console when it fails?

Comment: The code does not fail. The issue is how DocuSign page treats when code is run, vs when same action is performed manually, per description in my prior comment. I am not sure how you run your code. I make a bookmarklet out of it and execute it from favorites bar.

Comment: I just clicked on the link, I think that should be equivalent. But maybe there are ways to restrict what bookmarklets can do.

Comment: Well, in this case webpage does allow bookmarklet to run the code, resulting in character added to the field, but it treats that being done by code differently than when same thing is done manually.  I noticed similar issue in Excel's VBA in some instances.